# Confused by "Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer SP1" within Visual Studio 2008 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, servicepacks

I have Visual Studio 2008 Pro and was curious as to whether or not I had VS2008 SP1 installed.

I took a look at my "About Microsoft Visual Studio" and scrolled through the "Installed Products" list. I noticed that I have a bunch of VS2008 Hotfixes installed, but I did not notice an explicit item for a VS2008 PRO Service Pack 1.

However, I did notice that I have an item titled:
"*Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB945140)*"

I'm not for certain, but my guess is the Team Explorer SP1 was installed a while ago when I installed the "[Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86)" plugin.

Is the *VS2008 PRO Service Pack 1* installation implicit in the *Team Explorer Service Pack 1* installation? Or would I need to install PRO SP1 in addition to the TE SP1?

Comment: Please document your problem better.  What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague has sent me his list of installed products (for VS2008 Pro). His list includes:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
  Professional Edition - ENU Service
  Pack 1 (KB947888)
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
  Professional Edition - ENU Service
  Pack 1 (KB948484)
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team
  Explorer - ENU Service Pack 1
  (KB945140)

My list does not include either one of the VS2008 Pro service packs (strange that he has two listed).

So, to answer my own question - No, the Team Explorer SP1 doesn't implicitly include VS2008 Pro SP1. We should see a listed item for the VS Pro SP and a different one for the Team Explorer SP.

Strange that my list of installed products doesn't include a VS Pro SP. I suppose I should create a new post for that question.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the easiest way to know if I have 2008 SP1 installed is to look at the icon in the start bar when it is running.

If there is a 9 in the lower right corner you have SP1.  If not, then you don't have it installed.

To know for sure if you have it open up your Help->About in Visual Studio and look at the version number.

If it is 9.0.30729.xxx then you have SP1.
If it is 9.0.21022.8 then you have the RTM version.

Comment: My VS icon in the Task Bar does display "9" and my "About..." version is 9.0.30729.1. However, there is no listing of VS Pro SP1 installed in the list of "Installed products".